# R: Plotting matrix columns using formulas

Tags: r

Having just spent an hour chasing a 'matrix vs data.frame' bug in my code, I would very much like to understand the following:

```r
tmp <-
  structure(c(4L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8L),
            .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("col1", "col2")))

## 1. This works:
plot(col2 ~ col1, data = tmp)

## 2. This doesn't work:
plot(col2 ~ col1, data = tmp, main = "hello")
## -> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

## 3. This works:
plot(col2 ~ col1, data = as.data.frame(tmp), main = "hello")
```

It seems to me that either 1 and 2 should both work, or both fail. The fact that 1 worked while 2 failed lead me very far astray in trying to get my code working.

My question is: why can you *sometimes* use a formula to plot matrix columns, instead of *always* or *never*? What happens when I add a title to my plot to cause it to fail?

Edit:
I suspected I must have broken something myself, so I have already tried this exact code in multiple fresh R instances. My sessionInfo is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
```

Edit:

Here's the traceback() following the failed `plot` command:

```
> > traceback()
4: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
3: lapply(dots, eval, data, parent.frame())
2: plot.formula(col2 ~ col1, data = tmp, main = "hello")
1: plot(col2 ~ col1, data = tmp, main = "hello")
>
```

Edit:

Upgrading to 2.14 has resolved the issue.

Comment: Number 2 works for me (no error, gives plot with a title of "hello").  I can get your error with `plot(col2 ~ col1, data = c(1,2), main = "hello")` or `plot(col2 ~ col1, data = as.vector(tmp), main="hello")`.  I get a similar, but different error, with `plot(col2 ~ col1, data = as.vector(tmp))` which *is* surprising.

Comment: That shouldn't happen (and doesn't for me when I run this code). Can you try running just this code in a clean R session, just to double check?

Comment: All three examples work for me.  Please give more information, e.g. the result of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: No error on a Mac running 2.14.0. Need further info as described above: `sessionInfo()`, report of clean run, `traceback()`.

Comment: @joran: just to be sure I'm not crazy, I ran it again in a clean session, and the problem persists. I have posted my sessionInfo above.

Comment: Even "fresh" instances of R can carry old information from saved data.  Try either starting R with the `--vanilla` option to not load your previous workspace or rename the `.RData` in your directory (since it is the previous workspace) to something else so it won't get loaded.  You can see what is in your workspace with `ls()` and maybe see if there are multiple things with the same name with `conflicts()`.

Comment: @Dwin: I've posted my traceback

Comment: Your R version is fairly old (by R versioning standards). You could try updating your R installation, but that's just a guess on my part.

Comment: @Brian Diggs: I don't save my workspaces. But just to be sure, I tried running `R --vanilla` and still got the same problem.

Comment: I do see the same thing with R 2.12.1 (I was surprised I still had it on my machine); I don't know why it would do that, but it apparently is a bug that was fixed sometime between 2.12.1 and 2.14.0.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.14 has fixed the issue. So does this post have any archival value, or would it be best to delete it to remove the noise?

Comment: FWIW, The NEWS file for R 2.13.0 is probably referring to this issue when it mentions that, "* plot(<formula>, data=<matrix>,..) now works in more cases; similarly for points(), lines() and text()."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments thread following the question, it's clear that this **was** a problem in `R-2.12.1`, and **isn't** for `R-2.14.0`.

The `R-2.13.0` section of the `NEWS` file is presumably referring to this bug fix when it mentions that

> ```
> * plot(<formula>, data=<matrix>,..) now works in more cases;
>   similarly for points(), lines() and text().
> ```

(**NOTE:**  this answer is based on the digging of Tyler and numerous posters above. I'm elevating the conclusions of that thread to answer status, as a possibly useful reminder of the kind of bug-fixes that are included in each version of `R`.)